# Validate mmddyyyy date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to validate data in the format which in in mmddyyyy format
Date like 11171938
which is Nov 17 1938

Example

```
SELECT cast(stuff(stuff(RIGHT('0' + '021313', 6), 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-') AS DATE)
```

2013-02-13

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server has perfectly good date based datatypes, and in a well designed system should never have to deal with strings that might contain valid dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(10) = '11171938'

SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@String, 4) 
            + LEFT(@String , 4) AS DATE)
```

**Result**

```
1938-11-17
```

Comment: You can simplify your code to:  `right(@String, 4) + left(@string, 4)`.